# Android Async - Opening New Activity (intent) in onPostExecute in Android

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-alertdialog

I have an Android application that fetches values from the server with MySQL and PHP. The application is working fine, but after the alert box appears it is not redirecting to the next activity with class file VoterLogin.java.

Here's the code,

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
  //  ctx.startActivity(new Intent(ctx, VoterLogin.class));

    if(result.equals("Registration Success..."))
    {
      Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

The above code snippet is showing the following in LogCat:

```
05-25 23:51:16.694 2214-2214/? D/AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 0 <<<<<<<br>
05-25 23:51:16.699 2214-2214/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is ON<br>
05-25 23:51:16.726 2214-2214/? D/ICU: No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat<br>
05-25 23:51:16.761 2214-2214/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)<br>
05-25 23:51:16.761 2214-2214/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2<br>
05-25 23:51:16.763 2214-2214/? I/Radio-JNI: register_android_hardware_Radio DONE<br>
05-25 23:51:16.799 2214-2214/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm<br>
05-25 23:51:16.833 2059-2070/? D/DefContainer: Copying /data/local/tmp/amit.net.voteapplication to base.apk<br>
05-25 23:51:17.112 1300-1324/? I/PackageManager.DexOptimizer: Running dexopt (dex2oat) on: /data/app/vmdl1542992946.tmp/base.apk pkg=amit.net.voteapplication isa=x86 vmSafeMode=false debuggable=true oatDir = /data/app/vmdl1542992946.tmp/oat<br>
05-25 23:51:17.128 2223-2223/? W/dex2oat: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86<br>
05-25 23:51:17.128 2223-2223/? W/dex2oat: Mismatch between dex2oat instruction set features (ISA: X86 Feature string: smp,-ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2) and those of dex2oat executable (ISA: X86 Feature string: smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2) for the command line:<br>
05-25 23:51:17.129 2223-2223/? W/dex2oat: /system/bin/dex2oat --zip-fd=6 --zip-location=base.apk --oat-fd=7 --oat-location=/data/app/vmdl1542992946.tmp/oat/x86/base.odex --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --swap-fd=8 --debuggable<br>
05-25 23:51:17.129 2223-2223/? I/dex2oat: /system/bin/dex2oat --debuggable<br>
05-25 23:51:17.250 2223-2223/? W/dex2oat: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView<br>
05-25 23:51:25.864 2223-2223/? I/dex2oat: dex2oat took 8.735s (threads: 1) arena alloc=515KB java alloc=2MB native alloc=9MB free=1788KB<br>
05-25 23:51:25.907 1300-1314/? I/ActivityManager: Force stopping amit.net.voteapplication appid=10072 user=-1: uninstall pkg<br>
05-25 23:51:25.907 1300-1314/? I/ActivityManager: Killing 2181:amit.net.voteapplication/u0a72 (adj 0): stop amit.net.voteapplication<br>
05-25 23:51:25.911 1300-1337/? W/InputDispatcher: channel 'b7ef2f3 amit.net.voteapplication/amit.net.voteapplication.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9<br>
05-25 23:51:25.911 1300-1337/? E/InputDispatcher: channel 'b7ef2f3 amit.net.voteapplication/amit.net.voteapplication.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!<br>
05-25 23:51:25.912 1300-1312/? D/GraphicsStats: Buffer count: 4<br>
05-25 23:51:25.912 1300-1312/? I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{b7ef2f3 u0 amit.net.voteapplication/amit.net.voteapplication.MainActivity}<br>
05-25 23:51:25.913 1300-1312/? W/InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel 'b7ef2f3 amit.net.voteapplication/amit.net.voteapplication.MainActivity (server)'<br>
05-25 23:51:25.951 1300-1314/? W/ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{4bc60b9 u0 amit.net.voteapplication/.MainActivity t505}: app died, no saved state<br>
05-25 23:51:26.008 1300-1324/? I/PackageManager: Package amit.net.voteapplication codePath changed from /data/app/amit.net.voteapplication-2 to /data/app/amit.net.voteapplication-1; Retaining data and using new<br>
05-25 23:51:26.009 1300-1324/? W/PackageManager: Code path for amit.net.voteapplication changing from /data/app/amit.net.voteapplication-2 to /data/app/amit.net.voteapplication-1<br>
05-25 23:51:26.009 1300-1324/? W/PackageManager: Resource path for amit.net.voteapplication changing from /data/app/amit.net.voteapplication-2 to /data/app/amit.net.voteapplication-1<br>
05-25 23:51:26.056 1300-1315/? W/art: Long monitor contention event with owner method=void com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$MainHandler.handleMessage(android.os.Message) from ActivityManagerService.java:1698 waiters=0 for 149ms<br>
05-25 23:51:26.057 1300-1617/? W/art: Long monitor contention event with owner method=void com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$MainHandler.handleMessage(android.os.Message) from ActivityManagerService.java:1698 waiters=1 for 145ms<br>
05-25 23:51:26.058 1300-1617/? W/ActivityManager: Spurious death for ProcessRecord{647ac55 0:amit.net.voteapplication/u0a72}, curProc for 2181: null<br>
05-25 23:51:26.062 1300-1314/? I/ActivityManager: Force stopping amit.net.voteapplication appid=10072 user=-1: replace pkg<br>
05-25 23:51:26.229 1300-1324/? W/Settings: Setting install_non_market_apps has moved from android.provider.Settings.Global to android.provider.Settings.Secure, returning read-only value.<br>
05-25 23:51:26.230 1300-1324/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Explicit<br>
05-25 23:51:26.239 1542-1769/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented<br>
05-25 23:51:26.239 1542-1769/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa24b54e0, error=EGL_SUCCESS<br>
05-25 23:51:26.402 1300-1324/? I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 28767(1684KB) AllocSpace objects, 12(320KB) LOS objects, 33% free, 5MB/8MB, paused 4.654ms total 160.940ms<br>
05-25 23:51:26.421 1300-1566/? W/InputMethodManagerService: Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 2181 uid 10072<br>
05-25 23:51:26.835 1300-1324/? W/PackageManager: Couldn't remove dex file for package:  at location /data/app/amit.net.voteapplication-2/base.apk, retcode=-1<br>
05-25 23:51:26.850 2214-2214/? I/art: System.exit called, status: 0<br>
05-25 23:51:26.850 2214-2214/? I/AndroidRuntime: VM exiting with result code 0.<br>
05-25 23:51:26.870 1516-2136/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb4016980<br>
05-25 23:51:26.876 1300-1324/? I/ActivityManager: Force stopping amit.net.voteapplication appid=10072 user=0: pkg removed<br>
05-25 23:51:27.170 1300-1314/? W/art: Long monitor contention event with owner method=int com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntent(android.app.IApplicationThread, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String, android.content.IIntentReceiver, int, java.lang.String, android.os.Bundle, java.lang.String[], int, android.os.Bundle, boolean, boolean, int) from ActivityManagerService.java:16931 waiters=0 for 195ms
05-25 23:51:27.176 1300-1300/? D/JobSchedulerService: Receieved: android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED
05-25 23:51:27.187 1300-1338/? I/InputReader: Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010<br>
05-25 23:51:27.193 1536-1536/? D/CarrierServiceBindHelper: Receive action: android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED<br>
05-25 23:51:27.194 1536-1536/? D/CarrierServiceBindHelper: mHandler: 3<br>
05-25 23:51:27.217 1940-1940/? W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.startService:1221 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:581 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:581 com.android.keychain.KeyChainBroadcastReceiver.onReceive:12 android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver:2725 <br>
05-25 23:51:27.320 1382-1393/? I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 9677(427KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 5MB/8MB, paused 25.484ms total 140.042ms<br>
05-25 23:51:27.821 2228-2228/? D/AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 0 <<<<<<
05-25 23:51:27.823 2228-2228/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is ON
05-25 23:51:27.833 2232-2232/? D/AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 0 <<<<<<<br>
05-25 23:51:27.835 2232-2232/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is ON<br>
05-25 23:51:27.860 2228-2228/? D/ICU: No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat<br>
05-25 23:51:27.894 2228-2228/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)<br>
05-25 23:51:27.894 2228-2228/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
05-25 23:51:27.896 2228-2228/? I/Radio-JNI: register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
05-25 23:51:27.898 2232-2232/? D/ICU: No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat<br>
05-25 23:51:27.934 2232-2232/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)<br>
05-25 23:51:27.934 2232-2232/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2<br>
05-25 23:51:27.936 2232-2232/? I/Radio-JNI: register_android_hardware_Radio DONE<br>
05-25 23:51:27.944 2228-2228/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.wm.Wm<br>
05-25 23:51:27.945 2228-2228/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM<br>
05-25 23:51:27.968 2232-2232/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am<br>
05-25 23:51:27.988 1516-1516/? I/Choreographer: Skipped 46 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.<br>
05-25 23:51:27.995 1300-1399/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=amit.net.voteapplication/.MainActivity} from uid 0 on display 0<br>
05-25 23:51:28.016 2232-2232/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM<br>
05-25 23:51:28.032 1300-1338/? I/InputReader: Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010<br>
05-25 23:51:28.099 1300-1311/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 2247:amit.net.voteapplication/u0a72 for activity amit.net.voteapplication/.MainActivity<br>
05-25 23:51:28.328 2247-2247/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)<br>
05-25 23:51:28.372 1536-1536/? D/CarrierServiceBindHelper: Receive action: android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED<br>
05-25 23:51:28.374 1536-1536/? D/CarrierServiceBindHelper: mHandler: 3<br>
05-25 23:51:28.405 1542-1769/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb4014d10<br>
05-25 23:51:28.432 2247-2247/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/amit.net.voteapplication-1/lib/x86<br>
05-25 23:51:28.596 953-1336/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property<br>
05-25 23:51:28.597 2247-2260/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true<br>
05-25 23:51:28.721 2247-2260/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4<br>
05-25 23:51:28.740 1536-1536/? D/CarrierServiceBindHelper: Receive action: android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED<br>
05-25 23:51:28.744 1536-1536/? D/CarrierServiceBindHelper: mHandler: 3<br>
05-25 23:51:28.745 1536-1536/? D/CarrierConfigLoader: mHandler: 9 phoneId: 0<br />
05-25 23:51:28.753 1300-1338/? I/InputReader: Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010<br>
05-25 23:51:28.788 2247-2260/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented<br>
05-25 23:51:28.788 2247-2260/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xabdc20c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS<br>
05-25 23:51:29.192 1300-1319/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed amit.net.voteapplication/.MainActivity: +1s117ms<br>
05-25 23:51:29.240 1516-1516/? I/LatinIME: Starting input. Cursor position = -1,-1<br>
05-25 23:51:29.240 1516-1516/? E/RichInputConnection: Unable to connect to the editor to retrieve text.<br>
05-25 23:51:29.240 1516-1516/? D/RichInputConnection: Will try to retrieve text later.<br>
05-25 23:51:29.240 1516-1516/? I/InputAttributes: InputType.TYPE_NULL is specified<br>
05-25 23:51:29.246 1516-1516/? I/LatinIME: Starting input. Cursor position = 0,0<br>
05-25 23:51:29.399 1300-1313/? W/VoiceInteractionManagerService: no available voice recognition services found for user 0<br>
05-25 23:51:29.473 1516-2136/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented<br>
05-25 23:51:29.473 1516-2136/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xabebbac0, error=EGL_SUCCESS<br>
05-25 23:51:51.019 2247-2260/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented<br>
05-25 23:51:51.019 2247-2260/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xabdc2d20, error=EGL_SUCCESS<br>
05-25 23:51:51.289 2247-2260/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented<br>
05-25 23:51:51.289 2247-2260/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xabdfece0, error=EGL_SUCCESS<br>
05-25 23:51:54.372 2247-2260/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab794ca0<br>
05-25 23:51:56.204 2247-2260/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab794d10<br>
05-25 23:51:56.210 2247-2247/? W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.<br>
05-25 23:51:56.212 1300-1311/? W/InputMethodManagerService: Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4ab1e93 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@85a4ab3<br>
```

I have tried some things from StackOverflow, but none of them is working and the result after clicking the button is "Unfortunately, VoteApplication has stopped". Here, I am also listing the 3 code snippets which I have tried,

The following is code 1:

```
        #1
        Intent intent_name = new Intent();
        intent_name.setClass(ctx.getApplicationContext(), VoterLogin.class);
        ctx.startActivity(intent_name);
```

The following is code 2:

```
        #2
        ctx.startActivity(new Intent(ctx, VoterLogin.class));
```

The #2 is showing "Unfortunately error" with the following LogCat:

```
05-26 00:30:12.063 2586-2586/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
05-26 00:30:12.063 2586-2586/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
05-26 00:30:20.747 2604-2604/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
05-26 00:30:20.747 2604-2604/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
05-26 00:30:20.844 2602-2602/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
05-26 00:30:20.844 2602-2602/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
05-26 00:30:21.381 1542-1769/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa30c7df0
05-26 00:30:21.414 953-987/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property 
05-26 00:30:22.235 1516-1516/? E/RichInputConnection: Unable to connect to the editor to retrieve text.
05-26 00:30:28.926 2617-2617/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             Process: amit.net.voteapplication, PID: 2617
                                             android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {amit.net.voteapplication/amit.net.voteapplication.VoterLogin}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1794)
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1512)
                                                 at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3917)
                                                 at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3877)
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:784)
                                                 at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4200)
                                                 at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4168)
                                                 at amit.net.voteapplication.BackgroundTask.onPostExecute(BackgroundTask.java:146)
                                                 at amit.net.voteapplication.BackgroundTask.onPostExecute(BackgroundTask.java:30)
                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
05-26 00:30:28.971 953-953/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 953: eglCreateSyncKHR(1294): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
05-26 00:30:31.445 1300-1337/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '29ddb2b amit.net.voteapplication/amit.net.voteapplication.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
05-26 00:30:31.505 1300-2145/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa1b8b8b0
05-26 00:30:31.507 1300-1337/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '28520cd !Password! (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
05-26 00:30:31.641 1516-2136/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb4016980
```

The following is code 3:

```
        #3
        Intent login = new Intent(ctx, VoterLogin.class);
        login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        ctx.startActivity(login);
        ((Activity) ctx).finish();
```

The #3 is showing "Unfortunately error" with the following LogCat:

```
05-26 00:25:06.735 953-2137/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
05-26 00:25:07.391 1542-1769/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa31f75e0
05-26 00:25:07.795 1516-1516/? E/RichInputConnection: Unable to connect to the editor to retrieve text.
05-26 00:25:11.350 2551-2551/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             Process: amit.net.voteapplication, PID: 2551
                                             android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {amit.net.voteapplication/amit.net.voteapplication.VoterLogin}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1794)
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1512)
                                                 at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3917)
                                                 at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3877)
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:784)
                                                 at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4200)
                                                 at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4168)
                                                 at amit.net.voteapplication.BackgroundTask.onPostExecute(BackgroundTask.java:148)
                                                 at amit.net.voteapplication.BackgroundTask.onPostExecute(BackgroundTask.java:30)
                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
05-26 00:25:11.384 953-953/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 953: eglCreateSyncKHR(1294): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
05-26 00:25:13.569 1300-1337/? E/InputDispatcher: channel 'f478103 amit.net.voteapplication/amit.net.voteapplication.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
05-26 00:25:13.580 1300-1337/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '9098762 !Password! (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
05-26 00:25:13.611 1300-2145/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa1b8b990
05-26 00:25:13.945 1516-2136/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb40168a0
```

So, an exception is visible in LogCat -

```
ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {amit.net.voteapplication/amit.net.voteapplication.VoterLogin}
```

Here's my Manifest, kindly let me know the problem,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="amit.net.voteapplication"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name="amit.net.voteapplication.MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: "Unfortunately, VoteApplication has stopped".  In this case you will see exception stack in logcat, please update question with exception stack, otherwise all answers would be trail & error solutions.

Comment: LogCat added! Thanks for letting me know. I have added the LogCat for the first code that at least runs the code, but did not redirect to the next page.

Comment: Added more LogCat exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {amit.net.voteapplication/amit.net.voteapplication.VoterLogin}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

I think you forgot to declare the activity in your Manifest.

Comment: Thanks @npe, I have added the manifest. I never declare all the manifests in AndroidManifest.xml, only the parent activity "amit.net.voteapplication.MainActivity" gets added automatically. So, how shoudl I add the VoterLogin activity?

Comment: <activity android:name="VoterLogin" /> See links below for more details on how to add activities to the manifest - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
if(result.equals("Registration Success..."))
{
  Intent intent_name = new Intent();
    intent_name.setClass(ctx.this, VoterLogin.class);
    ctx.startActivity(intent_name);
  Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else
{
    Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    alertDialog.setMessage(result);
    alertDialog.show();
}
}
```

`
You have to add your activity in the manifest.xml and you can edit like this.

Comment: Thanks @Ramazan. I want the Intent to get work in else part, since my LOGIN works in else part. How can I do that?